# Basic Require.js initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm new at handling imports with require.js, my question is very simple, let' say I have this config.js script for require:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone'
  }
});
```

and that is the first script I incorporate in my index.html:

```
<script data-main="config.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

From this point on can I use jQuery $, underscore _ and so on or should I also import such libraries in my index.html? It is puzzling how sometimes it works sometimes not, so I guess I am not doing it right.

EDIT: I will explain my question a little better here:

1)

```
<script data-main="config.js" src="require.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "div.bar" )...
    //some other jquery
</script>
<script src="..">//some script which uses require</script>
```

is jQuery loading twice in this page?

2) I have some libraries which needs jQuery to work, can I just add them to the paths in the require config?

Comment: And where you try to use it, in index.html?

Comment: This looks ok to me but perhaps having a full working example would help. This helped me: http://www.ringabell.org/en/un-simple-guide-pour-debuter-avec-requirejs/

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the modules and provide a callback function to use them:

```
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
function   ($,        _,   backbone) {
    //the modules are all
    //loaded and can be used here now.
});
```